# multiples of x in a number

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers

suppose we are given a range from l to r.We are asked to find count of that numbers whose all digits are multiples of x. x can be any number from 1 to 9. For example, take l=20 and r=40 and x=2 then required numbers are 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 40 as multiples of x are 0,2,4,6,8.

I have written a code for that . It runs for some of the test case. I don't why it is giving wrong answer for most of the test case.

constraints : 1<=l<=r<=10^18.

my code :

```
  #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 #define ll long long int

 ll s1(vector<string> &v, ll N)
 {

ll i, j, n = v.size(), ans = 0;
string ss = "", s = "";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    s += v[i];
}
ss = to_string(N);

ll d = ss.length(), f = 0, x = n - 1, y = 1;


for (i = 1; i < d; i++)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        ans += x;
        y = x;
        continue;
    }
    y = y * n;
    ans += y;
}
ll z = 0;

for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
{
    f = 0; 

    for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (z == 0)
        {
            z++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if (s[i] < ss[j])
        {

            ans += pow(n, d - (j + 1));
            z++;
        }
        else if (s[i] == ss[j])
        {
            z++;
            f = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!f)
    {
        break;
    }
}
ans += f;

return and;
}

int main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);

int t;
cin >> t;

while (t--)
{
    ll l, r;
    ll k, i, g;

    cin >> l >> r >> k;
    vector<ll> v1;

    ll x = 0;
    while (x <= 9)
    {
        v1.push_back(x);
        x = x + k;
    }

    vector<string> s;

    for (i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    {
        g = v1[i];
        char c = g + '0';
        string d(1, c);
        s.push_back(d);
        //  cout << D[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << s1(s, r) - s1(s, l - 1) << '\n';

}

 }
```

Can anyone tell me the better logic for this question?

Comment: 1. using dynamic programming we can write a function `f(x,d)` that gives us the amount of numbers in range `[0,x]` such that every digit is a multiple of `d`, runtime of such function would be `O(log x)` 
2. then answer is simply `f(R,x) - f(L-1,x)`

Comment: It will help if you can give an example test case where it fails.

Comment: @Photon Can u please implement ur logic on l=301  r=600 and x=3?

Comment: @Photon that function which u are talking about is already there in my code, s1 function in my code does the same.

Comment: @Photon  please answer.

Comment: I think compiler added in some bugs, because of the unreadable layout ;)

Comment: @domen tell the proper approach.

Comment: @sukesh its not, your'e just looping over all values in range `[1,r]` which will be too slow (remember C++ can handle only about `10^9` operations in one second). Using dynamic programming we can achieve same calculation result in logarithmic time

Comment: @Photon can u please show ur dynamic programming code for the function that gives us the number of numbers in the range [0,x] such that every digit is a multiple of d,

Answer (score 0):

1. using dynamic programming we can write a function `f(x,d)` that gives us the amount of numbers in range `[0,x]` such that every digit is a multiple of `d`
2. dp states: `[position in X][is our number prefix == X prefix?]`
3. which will use `log10(X) * 2` space
4. starting state is obviously `[0][1]`
5. then we just fill up the dp table, especially easy using recursion where we just check whats the next digit we can add that holds all conditions
6. So total complexity of such dp function would be `O(log10(X) * 2 * 10)` or simply `O(log N)` if we remove constants
7. then answer is simply f(R,x) - f(L-1,x)

Sample code (C++):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long

ll dp[22][2]; //[position in X][is our number prefix == X prefix?]

ll do_dp(vector<int>&digits, int k, int pos = 0, bool isEq = true)
{
    if(pos >= digits.size())return 1;
    if(dp[pos][isEq] != -1)return dp[pos][isEq];

    dp[pos][isEq] = 0;
    for(int d = 0; d <= (isEq ? digits[pos] : 9); d++) //d is next digit
        if(d % k == 0) //multiple of k
        dp[pos][isEq] += do_dp(digits, k, pos+1, isEq && d == digits[pos]);

    return dp[pos][isEq];
}

ll solve(ll x, int k)
{
    vector<int>digits;
    while(x > 0){
        digits.push_back(x%10);
        x/=10;
    }
    reverse(digits.begin(),digits.end());
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof dp);
    return do_dp(digits, k);
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    ll t,l,r,k;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>l>>r>>k;
        cout<<solve(r,k) - solve(l-1,k)<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: why are u using last column in dp matrix?

Comment: @sukesh just realized its actually not needed, edited the answer